# Use trait blanket implementation to restrict type trait bounds in Rust?

Tags: rust

In the code below: [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c91c4e5f65cc764775095750a281bd71)

```
  //////////////////////////////////////
 // External code from another crate //
//////////////////////////////////////

trait FooExternal {
    fn foo(&self);
}

fn foo_external(f: impl FooExternal) {
    f.foo();
}

  /////////////////////////////////////
 // My generated library code below //
/////////////////////////////////////

trait FooImpl {
    fn foo_impl(&self);
}

impl<T: FooImpl> FooExternal for T {
    fn foo(&self) {
        println!("foo: boilerplate");
        self.foo_impl();
    }
}

  ////////////////////////
 // My user code below //
////////////////////////

#[derive(Debug, Default)]
struct Foo;

// NB: the compiler will yell if FooImpl is not implemented
// try commenting out the impl below
impl FooImpl for Foo {
    fn foo_impl(&self) {
        println!("foo_impl");
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
    let f = Foo::default();
    foo_external(f);
}
```

The external code expects user to supply a type that implements `FooExternal`, so `foo_external` can work on an instance of the type.

However, when implementing the `FooExternal` trait for a user defined struct `Foo`, there is some boilerplate code (e.g. setting up opentelemetry tracing span context for each tonic grpc handler) that is common and error prone and a little complex to require an end user to type out.

So I plan to generate (think: proc macro, but codegen is not the issue here!) the common boilerplate implementation of `FooExternal`, and want user to only focus on the core app logic, and not worrying about the complex and boring chore of typing the same boilerplate over and over again!

So, instead of having user to implement `FooExternal` for her type `Foo`, I want the user to implement a generated trait `FooImpl`, where in the generated blanket trait implementation of `FooExternal::foo`, the boilerplate code is emitted, and the control is forwarded to `FooImpl::foo_impl`.

Here's the nice thing in the user code: `FooImpl` becomes a requirement for the user type `Foo` (when using `foo_external`) - if the user forgets to implement `FooImpl` for `Foo`, the compiler would kindly yell at you when calling `foo_external(f)`!

So it seems that the trait blanket implementation effectively have `FooExternal` bound on `FooImpl` - even the compiler error message (when the `impl FooImpl for Foo` is commented out) says:

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Foo: FooImpl` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:49:18
   |
49 |     foo_external(f);
   |                  ^ the trait `FooImpl` is not implemented for `Foo`
   |
note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `FooExternal` for `Foo`
  --> src/main.rs:23:18
   |
23 | impl<T: FooImpl> FooExternal for T {
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^     ^
note: required by a bound in `foo_external`
  --> src/main.rs:11:25
   |
11 | fn foo_external(f: impl FooExternal) {
   |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `foo_external`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to previous error
```

So, I'm wondering that is trait blanket implementation ever designed to be used in such a scenario (basically tie `FooImpl` and `FooExternal` together, a little like extension trait `trait FooExternal: FooImpl`, but not quite!), and can I rely on this behavior to define my code generation logic to generate the library code as in the code sample?

Any insights would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [trait coherence rules](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/implementations.html#trait-implementation-coherence), `impl<T: FooImpl> FooExternal for T` must be in the same crate as `FooExternal`. So, if you do not control the crate `FooExternal` is defined in, you cannot do this.

The rules are are designed so that adding more crates can never *create* a conflict between trait implementations that wasn't there already. There can only be *one* blanket implementation `impl<T...> FooExternal for T` (because if there was more than one, they might both apply to the same type `T`), and only the crate defining `FooExternal` is allowed to write that implementation.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! I double checked, and fortunately, it seems `FooExternal` is actually inside my own crate, it’s just generated by tonic. So under this scenario, I guess my usage case does work and makes sense?

Comment: @Dejavu Yes, in that case it should work, but note that having the blanket impl doesn't stop other crates from directly implementing `FooExternal` and ignoring the blanket impl.